# How to plot L shape in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, animation

```
w1=0.178848 Cos[4.69409 x1] - 0.178848 Cosh[4.69409 x1] - 
 0.182206 Sin[4.69409 x1] + 0.182206 Sinh[4.69409 x1];
w2=-0.181744 Cos[4.69409 x2] - 0.178795 Cosh[4.69409 x2] + 
 0.185154 Sin[4.69409 x2] + 0.182152 Sinh[4.69409 x2];
```

Where `w1` and `w2` are the equation which governs the deformation of the verticle line and horizontal line respectively. The only constraint is  `w1(x1=1)=w2(x2=0)` and is taken into account in the formulation. But now I don't know how to plot this L shape line in 3d space. I tried Using `ParametricPlot3D` but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you really want to get, but it's possible that these curves

```
w1[x1_] := 
  0.178848 Cos[4.69409 x1] - 0.178848 Cosh[4.69409 x1] - 
   0.182206 Sin[4.69409 x1] + 0.182206 Sinh[4.69409 x1];
w2[x2_] := -0.181744 Cos[4.69409 x2] - 0.178795 Cosh[4.69409 x2] + 
   0.185154 Sin[4.69409 x2] + 0.182152 Sinh[4.69409 x2];
{ParametricPlot3D[{w1[t], w2[t], 0}, {t, -.1, 1.7}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{w1[t], w2[t], t}, {t, -.1, 1.7}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 ParametricPlot[{w1[t], w2[t]}, {t, -.1, 1.7}, ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Ok, I have an image file of what I need. How to upload the image file in the comment sections

Comment: @vijay You can edit your question and add the image to the description.